# LP formulation of $k$-opt moves

Tags: linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, heuristics

**Question:**
what is known about formulating $k$-opt moves that strive for improving the length of Hamilton cycles by means of exchanging $k$ of the tour edges with $k$ non-tour edges?
Specifically:

- are such formulations known?
- if not, would they be desirable, at least from a theoretical point of view?
- what can be said about their expected integrality gap?